# Issues with Power Automate Flow Not Executing Actions After SharePoint Item Creation

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop, power-automate-custom-connector, power-virtual-agents

I'm currently facing an issue with a workflow I've set up in Power Automate and was wondering if anyone could provide some assistance.

The workflow is designed to function as follows:

It's triggered when an item is created in my SharePoint list.

Next, the Office 365 Groups connector is used to list the members of a certain group.

This is followed by an "Apply to each" control. Within this control, a message is posted with the Power Virtual Agents to a chat with a bot. The action is configured to use the "Internal Communication" bot. The recipient of the message is determined by the "mail" value that is returned from the previous "List Group Members" step. The message being posted contains the chat content of the item that was created in SharePoint (the action that triggers the workflow).

However, when I try to test the workflow, it seems to get stuck in execution and doesn't perform any of the expected actions. I've left the workflow running for about 30 minutes, but nothing happened.

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening or can provide some guidance on how to resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]